# Text transformation of regex capture group using PROPER is ignored by REGEXREPLACE

Tags: worksheet-function, regex, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to change the case of part of a text string (sub-string) in Google Sheets.

I've tried and failed to apply the PROPER function to a regex capture group inside REGEXREPLACE.

The PROPER function (UPPER & LOWER too) is simply ignored.

The example formulas are simplified to illustrate the issue.

##### PROPER Fails

```
=REGEXREPLACE(
   "POPCORN",
   "^([[:upper:].*)",
   PROPER("$1"))

="POPCORN"
```

If I instead use the REGEXEXTRACT function to extract the string, I can wrap it in PROPER and it behaves as expected.

##### PROPER Succeeds

```
=PROPER(
   REGEXEXTRACT(
     "POPCORN",
     "^([[:upper:].*)")

="Popcorn"
```

Being able to use REGEXREPLACE with PROPER would simplify the formula.

Instead of using:

##### PROPER Fails

```
=REGEXREPLACE(text,regex,
              PROPER("$1"))
```

I am using the following approach:

##### PROPER Succeeds

```
=SUBSTITUTE(text,
   REGEXEXTRACT(text,regex),
   PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(text,regex))))
```

Or a variation

```
=LET(str,REGEXEXTRACT(text,regex),  
   SUBSTITUTE(text,str,PROPER(str)))
```

Is there a way to adjust the syntax in the formulas that are failing to successfully use PROPER in the REGEXREPLACE function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there'd be a way to simplify your formula.

`PROPER("$1")` is applied to the string `"$1"` and not to the match and there's no way to change this behaviour.